# PHP URL Form Validation

Tags: php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a form I am trying to build. Basically I'm using a basic bootstrap template for a form which already has built in php validation. Built-in, it validates specifically the email address. However I am trying to add in another field for a valid url and have php validate this other field to pass onto an e-mail.

Currently my code looks like this in the html:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h3>Order/Estimate Form</h3>
            <p style="color:red;">*Please Fill In All Fields*</p>
            <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Full Name:</label><p style="color:gray;">* required field</p>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Company</label>
                        <input type="company" class="form-control" id="company">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Phone Number:</label><p style="color:gray;">* required field</p>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Email Address:</label><p style="color:gray;">* required field</p>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Download Link</label><p style="color:gray;">* required field</p>
                        <input type="url" class="form-control" id="url" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a valid shareable download link from wetransfer.com">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Subject:</label><p style="color:gray;">* required field</p>
                        <input type="subject" class="form-control" id="subject" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a subject.">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Message:</label><p style="color:gray;">* required field</p>
                        <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="success"></div>
                <!-- For success/fail messages -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
```

And my php connected to this is as follows:

```
<?php
// check if fields passed are empty
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['subject'])   ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['url'])   ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   !filter_var($_POST['url'],FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// create email body and send it    
$to = 'mail@email.com'; // PUT YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS HERE
$email_subject = "Quote/Pricing Form:  $name"; // EDIT THE EMAIL SUBJECT LINE HERE
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website's contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nURL: $url\n\nSubject: $subject\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@email.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Additionally, here's the jQuery validation code:

```
$(function() {

$("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        // something to have when submit produces an error ?
        // Not decided if I need it yet
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var url = $("input#url").val();
        var subject = $("input#subject").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "./bin/contact_me.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: name,
                phone: phone,
                email: email,
                url: url,
                subject: subject,
                message: message
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                // Success message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append('</div>');

                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function() {
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + " it seems that my mail server is not responding...</strong> Could you please email me directly to <a href='mailto:me@example.com?Subject=Message_Me from myprogrammingblog.com;>me@example.com</a> ? Sorry for the inconvenience!");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
        })
    },
    filter: function() {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
});

$("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
});
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
$('#success').html('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [FILTER_VALIDATE_URL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_url.asp)

If you want to use jquery to validate this url first then you would simply have a call that checks the url to another php file and upon success you can then execute the rest of your jquery code.